# Use Flutter and Dart for embedded micro-controller development

Tags: flutter, dart, embedded

Being a Flutter developer, it would be nice to be able to use Flutter for development of embedded applications on micro-controllers to benefit from the developer productivity that comes with the workflow of using Flutter.

Is it possible to use Flutter for embedded development on micro-controllers and if not, what alternatives with similar developer workflows are available?

Answer (score 0):

Dart and hence Flutter do not and will likely will not ever in the future support low powered, micro-controllers running bare metal or a RTOS. While there was previously a project from Google called [Dartino](https://github.com/dart-archive/sdk) that did try to target small systems for Dart, this was cancelled in 2016 in favour of the Dart team at Google focusing on Flutter.

For micro-controller development using hardware such as the ESP range, RP2040, MicroBits,  nRF52X's, etc there are a number of options for a good developer experience for prototyping or hobbyist usage, having features such as a REPL and using easy scripting languages, such as JS-based [Espruino](https://www.espruino.com/), Lua-based [NodeMCU](https://www.nodemcu.com/index_en.html), Python-based [MicroPython](https://micropython.org/) and [Toit](https://toit.io/) which is actually from some of the original developers who worked on Dartino at Google. And there is of course also the very popular and mature C-based [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/).

However the line between SoC's running a full OS such as Linux and micro-controllers running bare-metal or an RTOS is blurring somewhat and very small SoC's such as the RISC-V based [0x64](https://wiki.pine64.org/wiki/Ox64) can run Linux and in theory should be able to run Dart and maybe even a cut down version of Flutter.